# Improve benchmark of function in R

Tags: r, recursion, benchmarking

I am currently dealing with a benchmarking problem and I am willing to use the vectorization of R for faster calculation however I do not really have a clue how I can improve the speed. Help is much appreciated.

```
function(n = 5, lower = 1, upper = 4, add = 1) {
  result <- c(lower, upper)
  for (i in 3:n) {
    result <- append(result, result[[i - 1]] + result[[i - 2]] + add)
  }
 result
}
```

My ideas included lapply/vapply as well as some sort of recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `append` in a loop. This is called "growing an object" where the `results` object gets bigger every iteration. It's notoriously inefficient because as the object gets bigger your computer has to find bigger and bigger places to store it in memory, moving it around and copying it a lot.

Instead, initialize `result` to its full length from the start. Set all the values you don't know to `NA` and fill them in with values as you go.

```
# original
foo = function(n = 5, lower = 1, upper = 4, add = 1) {
  result <- c(lower, upper)
  for (i in 3:n) {
    result <- append(result, result[[i - 1]] + result[[i - 2]] + add)
  }
 result
}
foo()

bar = function(n = 5, lower = 1, upper = 4, add = 1) {
  # initialize to full length
  result = integer(length = n)
  # set first two entries
  result[1:2] <- c(lower, upper)
  for (i in 3:n) {
    # fill in the rest of the blanks
    result[i] <- result[i - 1] + result[i - 2] + add
  }
 result
}

## same result
identical(foo(), bar())
# [1] TRUE


## about 40x faster when n = 1000 (looking at the iterations per second)
bench::mark(foo(n = 1000), bar(n = 1000))
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result  
#   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>  
# 1 foo(n = 1000)   1.73ms   1.95ms      497.    3.86MB    39.3    177    14      356ms <dbl [1…
# 2 bar(n = 1000)  51.87µs  53.46µs    18439.   11.81KB     4.13  8936     2      485ms <dbl [1…
# # … with 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Also note that with vectors you only need single brackets `[`. Use double brackets `[[` to extract a single item from a `list` class object.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use `recursion`, which slows down your performance. Also, you can use pre-allocated vector to store the updated values. Below is a benchmark

```
# OP's solution
f <- function(n = 10, lower = 1, upper = 4, add = 1) {
  result <- c(lower, upper)
  for (i in 3:n) {
    result <- append(result, result[[i - 1]] + result[[i - 2]] + add)
  }
  result
}


# A recursion implementation
f1 <- function(n = 10, lower = 1, upper = 4, add = 1) {
  if (n <= 2) {
    return(c(lower, upper)[1:n])
  }
  v <- Recall(n - 1)
  c(v, sum(tail(v, 2)) + add)
}

# for-loop version with pre-allocated vector 
f2 <- function(n = 10, lower = 1, upper = 4, add = 1) {
  v <- numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (i <= 2) {
      v[i] <- c(lower, upper)[i]
    } else {
      v[i] <- v[i - 1] + v[i - 2] + add
    }
  }
  v
}
```

and you will see

```
> microbenchmark(f(), f1(), f2())
Unit: microseconds
 expr  min   lq    mean median    uq     max neval
  f() 10.5 11.0 150.894  11.60 12.30 13738.9   100
 f1() 68.1 69.3 170.973  70.95 82.25  6796.3   100
 f2()  2.7  2.9 163.506   3.20  3.80 15966.3   100
```